# Inplace remove last n lines of files without opening them more than once in gawk?

Tags: awk

https://www.baeldung.com/linux/remove-last-n-lines-of-file

```
awk -v n=3 'NR==FNR{total=NR;next} FNR==total-n+1{exit} 1' input.txt input.txt 
01 is my line number. Keep me please!
02 is my line number. Keep me please!
03 is my line number. Keep me please!
04 is my line number. Keep me please!
05 is my line number. Keep me please!
06 is my line number. Keep me please!
07 is my line number. Keep me please!
```

Here is a way to remove the last n lines. But it is not done inplace and the file is read twice, and it only deals with one file at a time.

How can I inplace remove the last n lines of many files without opening them more than once with one gawk command but without using any other external commands?

Comment: You could try like: `awk -v n="3" -v total=$(wc -l < Input_file) 'FNR==total-n+1{exit} 1' Input_file` which will help you to get lines with single run itself, cheers.

Comment: I just want to use gawk without using any other external commands.

Comment: Any particular reason to choose `awk`? Using `head -n -3` would likely be the fastest solution. You'll have to add code for inplace editing, but that would be similar to what `inplace` option does for you.

Comment: @Sundeep : you'll be surprised how little time savings there is with `head` (`N = 1639779`):       `in0:  100MiB 0:00:00 [1006MiB/s] [1006MiB/s] [=>                      ] 10% ETA 0:00:00
     out9:  715MiB 0:00:00 [ 748MiB/s] [ 748MiB/s] [     <=>                                ]
      in0:  988MiB 0:00:00 [1.07GiB/s] [1.07GiB/s] [======================>] 100%            
( pvE 0.1 in0 < "${fn1}" | ghead -n -"$N"; )  0.43s user 0.73s system 117% cpu 0.982 total
6fa4d6fbf7a4900db216024d220322c9  stdin`
 …...

Comment: @Sundeep : …..     `in0:  338MiB 0:00:00 [3.30GiB/s] [3.30GiB/s] [=======>                ] 34% ETA 0:00:00
     out9:  715MiB 0:00:01 [ 684MiB/s] [ 684MiB/s] [  <=>                                   ]
      in0:  988MiB 0:00:00 [3.28GiB/s] [3.28GiB/s] [======================>] 100%            
( pvE 0.1 in0 < "${fn1}" | mawk2 -v N="$N" ; )  0.30s user 0.68s system 90% cpu 1.071 total
6fa4d6fbf7a4900db216024d220322c9  stdin`

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples please try following `awk` code. Without using any external utilities as per OP's request in question. We could make use of `END` block here of `awk` programming.

```bash
awk -v n="3" '
{
  total=FNR
  lines[FNR]=$0
}
END{
  till=total-n
  for(i=1;i<=till;i++){
    print lines[i]
  }
}
' Input_file
```

Answer (score 2):

single-pass `awk` solution that requires neither arrays nor `gawk`

— (unless your file is over `500 MB`, then it might be slightly slower) :

```
rm -f file.txt

jot -c 30 51 > file.txt

gcat -n file.txt | rs -t -c$'\n' -C'#' 0 5 | column -s'#' -t

 1  3       7   9      13   ?      19   E      25   K
 2  4       8   :      14   @      20   F      26   L
 3  5       9   ;      15   A      21   G      27   M
 4  6      10   <      16   B      22   H      28   N
 5  7      11   =      17   C      23   I      29   O
 6  8      12   >      18   D      24   J      30   P
```

> ```
> mawk -v __='file.txt' -v N='13' 'BEGIN { 
>
> OFS = FS = RS
>       RS = "^$"
>
> getline <(__); close(__)
>   
> print $!(NF -= NF < (N+=_==$NF) ? NF : N) >(__) }'
> ```

```
gcat -n file.txt | rs -t -c$'\n' -C'#' 6 | column -s'#' -t ;


 1  3       7   9      13   ?
 2  4       8   :      14   @
 3  5       9   ;      15   A
 4  6      10   <      16   B
 5  7      11   =      17   C
 6  8      12   >
```

Speed is hardly a concern :

> ```
> 115K rows 198 MB file took 0.254 secs
> ```

```
rows       = 115567. | UTF8 chars = 133793410. | bytes      = 207390680.

( mawk2 -v __="${fn1}" -v N='13' ; )  
0.04s user 0.20s system 94% cpu 0.254 total
 
rows       = 115554. | UTF8 chars = 133779254. | bytes      = 207370006.
```

> ```
> 5.98 million rows 988 MB file took 1.44 secs
> ```

```
rows       = 5983333. | UTF8 chars = 969069988. | bytes      = 1036334374.

( mawk2 -v __="${fn1}" -v N='13' ; )
0.33s user 1.07s system 97% cpu 1.435 total
 
rows       = 5983320. | UTF8 chars = 969068062. | bytes      = 1036332426.
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it, using GAWK, with option [The BEGINFILE and ENDFILE Special Patterns](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/BEGINFILE_002fENDFILE.html):

```
{ lines[++numLines] = $0 }
BEGINFILE { fname=FILENAME}
ENDFILE { prt() }

function prt(   lineNr,maxLines) {
    close(fname)
    printf "" > fname
    maxLines = numLines - n
    for ( lineNr=1; lineNr<=maxLines; lineNr++ ) {
            print lines[lineNr] > fname
    }
    close(fname)
    numLines = 0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I find that this is the most succinct solution to the problem.

```
$ gawk -i inplace -v n=3 -v ORS= -e '{ lines[FNR]=$0 RT }
ENDFILE {
    for(i=1;i<=FNR-n;++i) {
        print lines[i]
    }
}' -- file{1..3}.txt
```

Comment: You are right. I have deleted `BEGIN { delete lines[0] }`. I don't assume the last line ends with new line. So I use RT and set ORS as empty.

Comment: What if n is zero? In that case, the lastline without newline matters?